# Google maps API for adding current location in delivery address

Tags: android, ios, google-places-api

I want to get the API of Google maps which customers can add their current location as the delivery address, just like in swiggy or zomato.

Could you guys share the link for that API?

Answer (score 0):

The google API you are looking for is Geocoding API.

The Geocoding API is a service that provides geocoding and reverse geocoding of addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Do check out the [Google Maps Platform](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/) website to work with Google Maps. To use the Maps API either on Android, iOS or for a website you need to get an API key. The documentation contains instructions on how to get an API key for different platforms.

To reduce the scope of your search when working with Google Maps, check out [FindCurrentPlace](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#find_a_place_from_the_users_location) which basically calls `findCurrentPlace()` to find the current location of the user's device.